# Confused about variable scope using matplotlib -- axis object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have no idea why the following code works. If I comment out the ax assignment in main, it ceases to work. How does ax get in scope of the function? This is python version 2.7.2.

After a little more research, I've found that functions defined in this same code module see all variables in the **main** block. I had no idea python worked this way! Every variable in the **main** block is visible to all functions in the same source file. This does not strike me as desirable! It seems to violate what functions are about. I suppose this exception is made for **main** code blocks, but I would not have guessed it.

How do I prevent functions defined in this code module from seeing all variables in the **main** block?

```
import pylab as plt

def f():
    ax.plot([1],[2]) # How is this ever defined?
    return

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True) # If I comment this out, then ax is not defined error in function call
    plt.hold(True)
    f()
```

Comment: ? inside `f`, the interpreter looks for the symbol `ax`. If it can't find it, it looks for it in your global scope, where indeed `ax` is defined.

Comment: You should modify your function to take the `Axes` object as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, because functions in python always have access to the global namespace, which is their module's namespace.

You can use modules to isolate a function.

Simply define your function in a module, i.e. a file like `mymod.py`. It will be able to access only its module scope. Then you can use it in `myscript.py` as

```
#file myscript.py
from mymod import myfunction
#and now the function myfunction will not 'see' the variables defined in myscript.py
```

Answer (score 2):

"This does not strike me as desirable! It seems to violate what functions are about."

You should then simply avoid having global variables in your code. Note that the main block you're referring to, is the global namespace (of that module/script). There is an if-statement, but that doesn't mean the "main" block is suddenly a special function.

What you can do is this (which is often considered better anyway):

```
import pylab as plt

def f():
    ax.plot([1],[2]) # This is now never defined
    return

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True) # ax is now local to the main() function only.
    plt.hold(True)
    f()

if __name__ == "__main__":   # No parentheses for an if-statement; very un-Pythonic
    main()
```

Now, this will cause an error every time, because `ax` is defined only inside `main()`, and not in the global (module) namespace.

Comment: why would this be considered better? except for the tiny performance improvement of local variables, which is a weak point. You don't care about namespace pollution in scripts like this, I would say that in this case it would be better to not have a `if __name__` clause actually and just write the code.

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo It is the case where you like to (re)use the script as a module. Perhaps `main()` is some function that you might want to call from another script, and perhaps not. Imagine expanding this script into a module (but also as a standalone script), and writing a another (wrapper) script that takes of e.g. commandline option parsing; the latter script can then import this script, and execute main (possibly with same keyword arguments).